# What's wrong with this SQL statement - Syntax Error #1064?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, syntax-error

```
SELECT id, content, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) AS unixtime 
FROM data
ORDER BY id ASC 
WHERE unixtime <= CURDATE() LIMIT 10;
```

or

```
SELECT id, content, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) AS unixtime 
FROM data
ORDER BY id ASC 
WHERE unixtime < CURDATE() LIMIT 10;
```

all phpAdmin is telling me is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE unixtime <= CURDATE() LIMIT 10' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

You have the `ORDER BY` and `WHERE` clauses reversed.

```
SELECT id, content, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) AS unixtime 
FROM data
WHERE unixtime < CURDATE()
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10;
```

or

```
SELECT id, content, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) AS unixtime 
FROM data
WHERE unixtime <= CURDATE() 
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10;
```

I just realized that part of your issue because you are referencing an alias in your `WHERE` clause.:

```
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) <= CURDATE()
```

or

```
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) < CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT id, content, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) AS unixtime 
FROM data 
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) <= CURDATE() 
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT id, content, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) AS unixtime 
FROM data
WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)) < CURDATE() ORDER BY id ASC  LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the where statement before the order by statement.